# Ruby on Rails - Escape HTML Entities in JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I recently upgraded an old rails app from version 4 to 6, and have noticed that my json views (view jbuilder) are now escaping any HTML entity. For example, amersands are now appearing as `\u0026`. Previously, I was able to avoid this by setting `config.active_support.escape_html_entities_in_json = false` in my application.rb. This doesn't seem to do anything anymore...what's the rails 6 way to configure this?

Comment: [That still seems to be it](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-active-support).

Comment: Yup, I saw that as well...definitely not working for me at least. Finally found something that works...posted my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to get this working in Rails 6 by creating an initializer with the following contents:

```
ActiveSupport.escape_html_entities_in_json = false
```

No idea why the old way isn't working, especially as the documentation still says it is a valid configuration option (as of 2/27/2021).

Comment: It's possible the order of configuration has changed subtly and something else is switching it to true after you switch it false, or your other `config.active_support.escape_html_entities_in_json = false` is never being called. Where is it located? Maybe assign a watch variable to it.